# Table Issue in WYSIWYG Editor

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, wysiwyg

I'm creating an HTML WYSIWYG editor from scratch and I have an issue when it comes to tables. Somehow, I'm able to create the pretended number of columns but only one row (without the heading). I'd be thankful if anyone could tell what's the issue.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Text Editor</title>
</head>
<body>

        <div id="Ribbon">

<div id="Ribbon-3">
        <button class="RibbonBtn" id="TableButton" title="Insert Table"><i class="fas fa-table"></i></button>
        </div>

        </div>

        <div id="TextArea">
            <div id="WYSIWYG" contenteditable="true"></div>

        </div>

    </div>




</body>
</html>
```

**JS**

```
window.addEventListener("load",function(){

    $('#TableButton').click(function(){
        var colnum = prompt("Indicate the number of columns");
        var rownum = prompt("Indicate the number of rows");
        var table = "";
        var tablehead = "";
        var tablebodytext = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < colnum; i++) {
            tablehead += "<th>null</th>";
        }

        var tablebody = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < rownum; i++) {
            var tablebodyrow = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < colnum; i++) {
                tablebodyrow += "<td>null</td>";
            }
            tablebody += "<tr>" + tablebodyrow + "</tr>";
        }

        table = "<table><tr>" + tablehead + "</tr>" + tablebody+ "</table>";
        document.execCommand("insertHTML",false, table);
    });


},false);
```

[image]

I chose 5 columns and 4 rows, but instead it created 5 columns and only 1 row

Comment: Firstly, PLEASE DO NOT USE CAPS FOR YOUR QUESTION'S TITLE. Secondly, please provide a screenshot of what it looks like right now.

Comment: Please narrow this down to only the relevant code that represents the specific problem as in creating a [mcve]

Comment: Ok, I've shortened the code and put a screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the error. Such a dumb mistake... 
I was using the same "i" var for the nested for loop and its parent loop.

This is the right version:

```
$('#TableButton').click(function(){
        var colnum = prompt("Indicate the number of columns:");
        var rownum = prompt("Indicate the number of rows:");
        var table = "";
        var tablehead = "";
        var tablebodytext = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < colnum; i++) {
            tablehead += "<th>null</th>";
        }

        var tablebody = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < rownum; i++) {
            var tablebodyrow = "";
            for (var i1 = 0; i1 < colnum; i1++) {
                tablebodyrow += "<td>null</td>";
            }
            tablebody += "<tr>" + tablebodyrow + "</tr>";
        }

        table = "<table><tr>" + tablehead + "</tr>" + "<tbody>" + tablebody + "</tbody>" + "</table>";
        document.execCommand("insertHTML",false, table);
    });
```

Comment: Mark your question answered or delete it then

Comment: I can´t, yet. I have to wait 2 more days.